# K-Means multiple dimensions C#

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis, k-means

I would like to ask if somebody could give me a reference how to implement K-Means with multiple dimensions in c#?

I have followed tutorial for 2 dimensions in this website:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/k-means-data-clustering-using-c.aspx

But what if I want to have input with 7 parameters instead of 2?

rawData[0] = new double[] { 65.0, 220.0, 70.0, 80.0, 56.0, 10.0 };

instead of:

rawData[0] = new double[] { 65.0, 220.0 };

[Source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRfbbp1ImDLeU9PX0s5LTZ2Z3c/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the definition of SSQ (sum of squares) it uses a *sum* symbol that allows any number of dimensions.

There is no limitation to 2 dimensions.

The tutorial you used has flaws, but *not* this one. From a quick look, it's supposed to work with 7 dimensions, too. (It will likely just be *slow* and may yield rather bad clusterings)

Comment: Dear Anony-Mousse,

Thank you for an answer,

Could you recommend a reference to achieve a good clustering with more dimensions?

I would really like to follow a good example a have a good clustering script.

Thank you in advance, Petras

Comment: It's more a matter of a good implementation than a good reference. There are many details to pay attention to, and you will find them in no reference because they are "just technical details".